# Function Calls and Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, call, function-calls, function-call

Im trying to understand how a program makes a function call (using C semantics) with assembly x86 code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I could not find any sources to specifically answer this question.

Comment: By far the easiest way to understand this is to write a C program and compile it using your favorite compiler with the option to have an output listing generated, or - failing that - by running the application under the debugger.

Comment: Any answer that will be useful to you will depend on the ABI you're targeting.  What machine/environment/toolchain are you working with?

Comment: Are you looking for understand some calling convention?

Comment: Thousands of hits with a Google of "assembly x86 code function call" - the first one is quite nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In x86, there are the instructions called `call` and `ret` to do this. `call` store the current address on stack and jmp to a label passed as argument. And the instruction called `ret` pop this address and jump to it after add one byte to that address.

Code example:

**C**

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}

void f(void)
{
  sum(2, 2);
  g();
}
```

A compiler might generate(x86-assembly-like example):

```
f:
  push 2
  push 2
  call sum
  call g
  ret

sum:
   pop eax
   pop ebx
   add eax, ebx
   ret
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with the following resources in the past.

- http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html
- http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html
- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Conventions
- https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/c-prog-mixing.html
- [Calling C functions from x86 assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255608/calling-c-functions-from-x86-assembly-language)

If you're looking for how function calls are translated to assembly, look for the `__cdecl` calling convention in the links above. Basically, different calling conventions specify different (and not always standardized) ways to pass parameters by manipulating the stack, and `__cdecl` is just one of the ways - the "C" calling convention.

If you're wondering how to call a C function from assembly code, the last two links are pretty good.

One other word of advice I can give is that if you have an assembly function that you want to call from C, specify the calling convention in the function declaration in C. For example, I once wrote assembly code following the `__stdcall` calling convention instead of `__cdecl`, so in the function signature I explicitly specified the `__stdcall` convention.