# clang doesn't use intel assembly syntax

Tags: x86, clang, inline-assembly, clang++, intel-syntax

I'm trying to compile an inline assembly code in clang (Windows). So,I have the following code:

```
int main(int, char **) {
  asm("mov %eax,$4;");
}
```

I tried compiling it using `clang++ -masm=intel main.cpp` but it complains about mnemonic operand size `main.cpp:4:7: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix`, because it was still using AT&T syntax.
I have tried using

```
asm(".intel_syntax;"
      "mov %eax,$4;");
```

But it complains about using .intel_syntax `main.cpp:3:7: error: unknown token in expression asm(".intel_syntax;")`

Comment: [Last I checked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58154963/224132), it didn't seem possible to get clang to use Intel-syntax inline asm.

Comment: This would be a better example if it wasn't totally broken.  e.g. `asm("mov $4, %eax" ::: "eax")` for the AT&T example.  (source first, destination last, and a clobber to tell the compiler about the register you step on).  And your intel-syntax attempt is still using AT&T decorations on register names and immediates.  The GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` version of that instruction is `mov eax, 4`.  Clang's assembler would reject that even in a stand-alone `.s` file.

Comment: Adding `noprefix` seems to work but it brakes when using inputs/ouputs. for example `asm(".intel_syntax noprefix; mov eax,%0 \n\t" ::"i"(10): "eax");`, gives the error ` error: unknown token in expression mov eax,$10`, it seems the prefix is added to inputs/ouputs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set gcc or clang to use Intel syntax permanently for inline asm() statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953951/how-to-set-gcc-or-clang-to-use-intel-syntax-permanently-for-inline-asm-stateme)